# jQuery: Return data after ajax call success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have something like this, where it is a simple call to a script that gives me back a value, a string..

```
function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php",  
      success: function(data) {
         return data; 
      }
   });
}
```

but if I call something like this

```
var output = testAjax(svar);  // output will be undefined...
```

so how can I return the value?
the below code does not seem to work either...

```
function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php",  
      success: function(data) {

      }
   });
   return data; 
}
```

Comment: this may help you . http://codingbin.com/get-return-data-ajax-call/

Answer (score 427, accepted):

The only way to return the data from the function would be to make a synchronous call instead of an asynchronous call, but that would freeze up the browser while it's waiting for the response.

You can pass in a callback function that handles the result:

```
function testAjax(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"getvalue.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
    }
  });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
testAjax(function(output){
  // here you use the output
});
// Note: the call won't wait for the result,
// so it will continue with the code here while waiting.
```

Comment: I guess adding [success] status would delay some and more accurate to only call when status is 400 successful.

Comment: @iamsirjayesh I'll do math for you, only 5.5 years! ...however helpful answer.

Comment: @Cirelli94: poor me at maths :p

Comment: `success` and `error` are being deprecated in jQuery 1.8. You should start using `.done()` and `.fail()`. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: What are being deprecated are the callback-manipulation functions (e.g. .error, .success) not the parameters to the ajax method. See the comments in this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931891/4490454

Comment: I know this is old but the calling part makes no sense to me.  What if I wanted to store the "output" to a variable to be  used in a conditional statement.   "Here you use the output doesnt make much sense to me.  I would like to just get the value out of the call to the testAjax function

Comment: @Mike: The thing is that you can't get the result out from the call unless you have a TARDIS. As the call is asynchronous, the result will arrive after the call returns. You can look into using promises provided in other answers here, which will let you return something from the call eventhough the result hasn't arrived yet. At some point you have to wait for the result anyhow, a promise just lets you do that in a different part of the code.

Comment: var res = testAjax(function(output){
 return(output);
});    not working !!!!!

Comment: @Guffa can you help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285958/dates-fetched-using-ajax-but-not-highlighted-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-php?noredirect=1#comment124251995_70285958

Answer (score 453):

***Note: This answer was written in February 2010.
See updates from 2015, 2016 and 2017 at the bottom.***

You can't return anything from a function that is asynchronous. What you can return is a *promise*. I explained how promises work in jQuery in my answers to those questions:

- [JavaScript function that returns AJAX call data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150571/javascript-function-that-returns-ajax-call-data/5150650#5150650)
- [jQuery jqXHR - cancel chained calls, trigger error chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111695/jquery-jqxhr-cancel-chained-calls-trigger-error-chain/5112734#5112734)

If you could explain **why** do you want to return the data and what do you want to do with it later, then I might be able to give you a more specific answer how to do it.

Generally, instead of:

```
function testAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "getvalue.php",  
    success: function(data) {
      return data; 
    }
  });
}
```

you can write your testAjax function like this:

```
function testAjax() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php"
  });
}
```

Then you can get your promise like this:

```
var promise = testAjax();
```

You can store your promise, you can pass it around, you can use it as an argument in function calls and you can return it from functions, but when you finally want to **use** your data that is returned by the AJAX call, you have to do it like this:

```
promise.success(function (data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

*(See updates below for simplified syntax.)*

If your data is available at this point then this function will be invoked immediately. If it isn't then it will be invoked as soon as the data is available.

The whole point of doing all of this is that your data is not available immediately after the call to $.ajax because it is asynchronous. Promises is a nice abstraction for functions to say: I can't return you the data because I don't have it yet and I don't want to block and make you wait so here's a *promise* instead and you'll be able to use it later, or to just give it to someone else and be done with it.

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jW68r/).

### UPDATE (2015)

Currently (as of March, 2015) jQuery Promises are not compatible with the [Promises/A+ specification](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) which means that they may not cooperate very well with other [Promises/A+ conformant implementations](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md).

However jQuery Promises in the upcoming version 3.x **will** be compatible with the Promises/A+ specification (thanks to [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) for pointing it out). Currently (as of May, 2015) the stable versions of jQuery are 1.x and 2.x.

What I explained above (in March, 2011) is a way to use [jQuery Deferred Objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to do something asynchronously that in synchronous code would be achieved by returning a value.

But a synchronous function call can do two things - it can either return a value (if it can) or throw an exception (if it can't return a value). Promises/A+ addresses both of those use cases in a way that is pretty much as powerful as exception handling in synchronous code. The jQuery version handles the equivalent of returning a value just fine but the equivalent of complex exception handling is somewhat problematic.

In particular, the whole point of exception handling in synchronous code is not just giving up with a nice message, but trying to fix the problem and continue the execution, or possibly rethrowing the same or a different exception for some other parts of the program to handle. In synchronous code you have a call stack. In asynchronous call you don't and advanced exception handling inside of your promises as required by the Promises/A+ specification can really help you write code that will handle errors and exceptions in a meaningful way even for complex use cases.

For differences between jQuery and other implementations, and how to convert jQuery promises to Promises/A+ compliant, see [Coming from jQuery](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery) by Kris Kowal et al. on the Q library wiki and [Promises arrive in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-javascript-promises) by Jake Archibald on HTML5 Rocks.

#### How to return a real promise

The function from my example above:

```
function testAjax() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php"
  });
}
```

returns a jqXHR object, which is a jQuery [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

To make it return a real promise, you can change it to - using [the method from the Q wiki](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery#converting-jquery-promises-to-q):

```
function testAjax() {
  return Q($.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php"
  }));
}
```

or, using [the method from the HTML5 Rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-javascript-promises):

```
function testAjax() {
  return Promise.resolve($.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php"
  }));
}
```

This `Promise.resolve($.ajax(...))` is also what is [explained in the `promise` module documentation](https://github.com/then/promise#promiseresolvevalue) and it should work with [ES6 `Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

To use the ES6 Promises today you can use [es6-promise module's `polyfill()`](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise#auto-polyfill) by Jake Archibald.

To see where you can use the ES6 Promises without the polyfill, see: [Can I use: Promises](http://caniuse.com/promises).

For more info see:

- http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14510
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1722
- https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970
- http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

#### Future of jQuery

Future versions of jQuery (starting from 3.x - current stable versions as of May 2015 are 1.x and 2.x) will be compatible with the [Promises/A+ specification](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) (thanks to [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum) for pointing it out in the comments). *"Two changes that we've already decided upon are Promise/A+ compatibility for our Deferred implementation [...]"* ([jQuery 3.0 and the future of Web development](http://sdtimes.com/jquery-3-0-future-web-development/)). For more info see: [jQuery 3.0: The Next Generations](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/10/29/jquery-3-0-the-next-generations/) by Dave Methvin and [jQuery 3.0: More interoperability, less Internet Explorer](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2843689/javascript/jquery-3-0-internet-explorer.html) by Paul Krill.

#### Interesting talks

- [Boom, Promises/A+ Was Born](http://youtu.be/V2Q13hzTGmA) by Domenic Denicola (JSConfUS 2013)
- [Redemption from Callback Hell](http://youtu.be/hf1T_AONQJU) by Michael Jackson and Domenic Denicola (HTML5DevConf 2013)
- [JavaScript Promises](https://youtu.be/oa2clhsYIDY) by David M. Lee (Nodevember 2014)

### UPDATE (2016)

There is a new syntax in [ECMA-262, 6th Edition, Section 14.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) called [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that may be used to further simplify the examples above.

Using the jQuery API, instead of:

```
promise.success(function (data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

you can write:

```
promise.success(data => alert(data));
```

or using the Promises/A+ API:

```
promise.then(data => alert(data));
```

Remember to always use rejection handlers either with:

```
promise.then(data => alert(data), error => alert(error));
```

or with:

```
promise.then(data => alert(data)).catch(error => alert(error));
```

See this answer to see why you should always use rejection handlers with promises:

- [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)

Of course in this example you could use just `promise.then(alert)` because you're just calling `alert` with the same arguments as your callback, but the arrow syntax is more general and lets you write things like:

```
promise.then(data => alert("x is " + data.x));
```

Not every browser supports this syntax yet, but there are certain cases when you're sure what browser your code will run on - e.g. when writing a [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), a [Firefox Add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons), or a desktop application using Electron, NW.js or AppJS (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803346/i-want-to-use-nodejs-as-front-end-and-back-end-in-my-application-can-you-sugges/35888163#35888163) for details).

For the support of arrow functions, see:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions
- http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-arrow_functions

### UPDATE (2017)

There is an even newer syntax right now called async functions with a new `await` keyword that instead of this code:

```
functionReturningPromise()
    .then(data => console.log('Data:', data))
    .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
```

lets you write:

```
try {
    let data = await functionReturningPromise();
    console.log('Data:', data);
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
}
```

You can only use it inside of a function created with the `async` keyword. For more info, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

For support in browsers, see:

- http://caniuse.com/async-functions

For support in Node, see:

- http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions

In places where you don't have native support for `async` and `await` you can use Babel:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/

or with a slightly different syntax a generator based approach like in `co` or Bluebird coroutines:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/co
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

## More info

Some other questions about promises for more details:

- [promise call separate from promise-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720512/promise-call-separate-from-promise-resolution/40721397#40721397)
- [Q Promise delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287845/node-q-promise-delay/41287978#41287978)
- [Return Promise result instead of Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719024/return-promise-result-instead-of-promise-in-nodejs/41719314#41719314)
- [Exporting module from promise result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279796/exporting-node-module-from-promise-result/41279904#41279904)
- [What is wrong with promise resolving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284107/what-is-wrong-with-promise-resolving/41284674#41284674)
- [Return value in function from a promise block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785769/return-value-in-function-from-a-promise-block/40785901#40785901)
- [How can i return status inside the promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764599/how-can-i-return-status-inside-the-promise/39765591#39765591)
- [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)
- [Is the deferred/promise concept in JavaScript a new one or is it a traditional part of functional programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845328/is-the-deferred-promise-concept-in-javascript-a-new-one-or-is-it-a-traditional-p/11845403#11845403)
- [How can I chain these functions together with promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Promise.all in JavaScript: How to get resolve value for all promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643386/promise-all-in-javascript-how-to-get-resolve-value-for-all-promises/40643489#40643489)
- [Why Promise.all is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308568/promise-all-in-node-is-undefined/41308699#41308699)
- [function will return null from javascript post/get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071337/function-will-return-null-from-javascript-post-get/42072290#42072290)
- [Use cancel() inside a then-chain created by promisifyAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515775/use-cancel-inside-a-then-chain-created-by-promisifyall/40515981#40515981)
- [Why is it possible to pass in a non-function parameter to Promise.then() without causing an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094764/why-is-it-possible-to-pass-in-a-non-function-parameter-to-promise-then-without/42094874#42094874)
- [Implement promises pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245867/implement-promises-pattern/15246695#15246695)
- [Promises and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985066/nodejs-promises-and-performance/37986778#37986778)
- [Trouble scraping two URLs with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305539/nodejs-trouble-scraping-two-urls-with-promises/41305907#41305907)
- [http.request not returning data even after specifying return on the 'end' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744595/nodejs-http-request-not-returning-data-even-after-specifying-return-on-the-end/41744917#41744917)
- [async.each not iterating when using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567353/async-each-not-iterating-when-using-promises/41567712#41567712)
- [jQuery jqXHR - cancel chained calls, trigger error chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111695/jquery-jqxhr-cancel-chained-calls-trigger-error-chain/5112734#5112734)
- [Correct way of handling promisses and server response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661064/correct-way-of-handling-promisses-and-server-response/39661503#39661503)
- [Return a value from a function call before completing all operations within the function itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081417/could-node-feasibly-return-a-value-from-a-function-call-before-completing-all-op/42088840#42088840)
- [Resolving a setTimeout inside API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729806/resolving-a-settimeout-inside-api-endpoint/40730062#40730062)
- [Async wait for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741374/async-wait-for-a-function/40741587#40741587)
- [JavaScript function that returns AJAX call data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150571/javascript-function-that-returns-ajax-call-data/5150650#5150650)
- [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await/40886720#40886720)
- [jQuery Deferred not calling the resolve/done callbacks in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159304/jquery-deferred-not-calling-the-resolve-done-callbacks-in-order/5159765#5159765)
- [Returning data from ajax results in strange object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660596/returning-data-from-ajax-results-in-strange-object/12660711#12660711)
- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)

Comment: They are just messing around with ajax, seeing how it works.

Comment: Perfect answer!Just to add a side note for users, this will not work with jQuery ver 1.4.

Comment: This helped a lot. I just skipped on step `var promise = testAjax()` and did this

`testAjax().success(function (data) {
  alert(data);
});`

Comment: @rsp great answer indeed! But I've followed your demo code, and it seems to call ajax twice (does anyone else noticed the same?).

Comment: @isurfbecause by using your approach, the ajax is only called once (as I needed).

Comment: Worth mentioning that Promises/A+ promises _are_ in jQuery in the 3.0 branch.

Comment: How about multiple data variables? Like `data.users`, `data.prices` ?

Comment: @AlexG In place of `promise.success(function (data) { alert(data); });` in my example you can use `promise.success(function (data) { alert(data.users[0].id); alert(data.prices[x]); });` or something like that. If you get the data in the `success` callback (or `then` callback, if you're using the Promises/A+ API) then you get the data with all of its properties.

Comment: is there a full example of using async with jquery 3.X ajax call?  I can't seem to find a proper(without something or another being deprecated) example (this is getting absurdly confusing)

Answer (score 224):

you can add async option to false **and** return outside the ajax call.

```
function testAjax() {
    var result="";
    $.ajax({
      url:"getvalue.php",
      async: false,  
      success:function(data) {
         result = data; 
      }
   });
   return result;
}
```

Comment: You solution is perfectly valid. I just want to emphasize the importance of not returning the value right away inside the success callback, but outside of the .ajax function call. Otherwise you will get undefined.

Comment: is there any way to use this function with async:true ?

Comment: `async: false` is now deprecated in [whatwg spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open%28%29-method) for most use cases. Google Chrome already warns about this in its console when a call occurs with `async: false`. [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open%28%29-method) does not seem to have deprecated it yet.

Comment: why doesn't this work?

function get_cmd_info3(cmd){
 var result = null;
 $.get("bash/"+cmd, 
 function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  result = data
 }, 'json');
 return result;
}

Comment: this didn't wrk for mi.. the result is coming as undefined in my return statement!

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: async: false, option is very important otherwise it throws undefined error

Comment: using `async: false` makes my code works, but takes some time to get the data. maybe that's why it is about to be ommitted. any solution for this? what's the proper way now?

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you guys solved it but I recommend another way to do it, and it works :)

```
    ServiceUtil = ig.Class.extend({
        base_url : 'someurl',

        sendRequest: function(request)
        {
            var url = this.base_url + request;
            var requestVar = new XMLHttpRequest();
            dataGet = false;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                async: false,
                type: "get",
                success: function(data){
                    ServiceUtil.objDataReturned = data;
                }
            });
            return ServiceUtil.objDataReturned;                
        }
    })
```

So the main idea here is that, by adding async: false, then you make everything waits until the data is retrieved. Then you assign it to a static variable of the class, and everything magically works :)

Comment: This was already proposed in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7891780/218196). In general, making synchronous Ajax requests is not a good idea.

Answer (score -14):

See jquery docs example:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
(about 2/3 the page)

You may be looking for following code:

```
    $.ajax({
     url: 'ajax/test.html',
     success: function(data) {
     $('.result').html(data);
     alert('Load was performed.');
   }
});
```

Same page...lower down.

Comment: NO
What if the result is needed in further processing inside another function ?, how are you going to pass it there ?